# Prove that $\int_{0 \le u \le 1,\Omega}g^2(x)udx$ in term of $u$ is convex

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am having a cost function and I want to know whether convex or not. Could you explain help me my problem? My problem is that given a cost function such as
$$F(u)=\int_{0 \le u(x) \le 1,\Omega}g^2(x)u(x)dx+\int \|\nabla u(x) \|dx$$

where $g: \Omega \to \mathbb R$,$u(x)>0$  and $\sum_i u_i(x) =1$ the second term looks like total variance, then it is convex function.

My problem is that how to prove $F(u)$ is a convex function?

In addition, if I have two function: first is convex and second is also convex function. Is sum of two functions convex or not?

Comment: What is $u$? function, vector, or vector-valued function? how is the first integral in $F$ defined? The condition $\sum u_i=0$ does not fit to the rest of the question.

Comment: $u$ is function that is $u(x) \in [0,1]$. Because you made a example about $u_1,u_2$, so I inserted a constrain that $\sum u_i=1$

Comment: This cannot be answered without knowledge of $g$.

Comment: @MichaelGrant: $g$ is function to map $x$ from $\Omega$ space to real number. Hence $g^2(x) \ge 0$

Comment: Then the first term is linear in $u$, so that's good. But the second term is not well-posed; it's an indefinite integral in $u$?

Comment: I corrected it. It is integral of $x$. It is total variance term then it is convex term

Comment: @MichaelGrant: Can you answer my question? Now it is more clear to understand